# Autocompletado con un datalist de HTML5 populado desde PHP

Tags: php, html, html5

Hace unos dias descubri que con html se puede hacer un autocompletado sin usar jQuery o alguna otra herramienta e hice esto:

categoriaClubFutbol.php

```
<label for="club" class="form-label">Clubes</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="club" id="club" list="miLista">
<datalist id="miLista">
    <?php foreach($datos as $c){ ?>
       <option value="<?=$c['id'];?>"><?=$c['club'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</datalist>
```

Funciona bien, pero el error que tengo es que si selcciono el club dentro del `input` me muestra `id` y no el nombre del equipo.

Este es un ejemplo sin `PHP`

```html
<label for="club" class="form-label">Clubes</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="club" list="miLista">
    <datalist id="miLista">
           <option value="1">Boca</option>
           <option value="2">River</option>
           <option value="3">Independiente</option>
           <option value="4">Racing</option>
    </datalist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese es el comportamiento por diseño cuando tiene un `value`.
En vez de usar el id dentro del `value`, podrías poner el texto con el nombre del equipo y guardar el id en una propiedad `data` extra.

```
<datalist id="miLista">
       <option data-id="2" value="River">
       <!-- y el resto -->
</datalist>
```

Desde JavaScript no hay una forma muy directa de obtener el `data-id` seleccionado, porque un datalist no está asociado a un input (y puede usarse en muchos inputs diferentes). Estos serían los pasos:

```html
<label for="club" class="form-label">Clubes</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="club" list="miLista" autocomplete="on">
    <datalist id="miLista">
           <option data-id="1" value="Boca">
           <option data-id="2" value="River">
           <option data-id="3" value="Independiente">
           <option data-id="4" value="Racing">
    </datalist>
  
<script>
    const club = document.getElementById('club');
    
    //evento cuando cambia el input
    club.addEventListener('change', clubChange);
    function clubChange(evt) {
        const input = evt.target,
              idDatalist = input.getAttribute('list');
        
        //obtener el datalist que le corresponde
        let datalist;
        if (idDatalist && (datalist = document.getElementById(idDatalist))) {

            //obtener la opcion seleccionada

            let opcionSel = datalist.querySelector(`option[value="${ input.value }" i]`);
            if (opcionSel) {
                //obtener el data-id de esa opcion
                let idClub = opcionSel.dataset.id;

                //acá está el valor

                console.log('value =',input.value, '\tid =', idClub);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Lo que hice fue: obtener el atributo `list="miLista"` y referenciar el elemento con ese id (el datalist). Luego, dentro de ese datalist, buscar el option cuyo `value` sea igual al valor que tiene el input. Al obtener el option, recién ahí se tiene el `data-id`.

Comment: Gracias Pollo, no tuve en cuenta `data-id`, voy a probar que ingresa a la base de datos y luego sigo molestando!

Comment: Creo que en donde puse `acá está el valor`, podrías asignarle ese `data-id` al input. O sea: `input.dataset.id = idClub` Me parece que simplificaría todo... Pero ahí ya tiene que ver con decisiones de cómo armar tu propio código, así que preferí dejarlo librado a gusto del consumidor

Comment: Ah entiendo, bueno, voy a probarlo. Gracias!